# SQL command to export post_content from wp_posts using phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to select all the data from within the `post_content` column in the `wp_posts` table in WordPress so I can export/import it into a new database. Somehow this content didn't properly make it from the old to new database.

Comment: `SELECT post_content from wp_posts` ?

Comment: Holy crap, is it really that easy? I had no idea. Yeah, that seems to have done it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use This Script

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username   = YOUR_USER;
$password   = YOUR_PASSWORD;
$dbname     = YOUR_DB_NAME;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
$a1 = ($_GET['id']); 
$sql = "SELECT post_content FROM `wp_posts` where ID='$a1'";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo $row["post_content"];
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

**Don't Forget To Change Your Database Details Above**